# Submitting remote spark job from eclipse IDE, getting paranamer error

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I'm submitting remote spark job to the cluster using the yarn-client mode using eclipse IDE.

But getting below error message in the eclipse IDE.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thoughtworks/paranamer/BytecodeReadingParanamer
    com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.BeanIntrospector$.<init>(BeanIntrospector.scala:40)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.BeanIntrospector$.<clinit>(BeanIntrospector.scala)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.ScalaPropertiesCollector.<init>(ScalaPropertiesCollector.scala:22)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.ScalaClassIntrospector$.constructPropertyCollector(ScalaClassIntrospector.scala:24)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.collectProperties(BasicClassIntrospector.java:142)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.forSerialization(BasicClassIntrospector.java:68)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.forSerialization(BasicClassIntrospector.java:11)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig.introspect(SerializationConfig.java:490)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.createSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:133)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:873)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:833)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:387)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findTypedValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:478)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:97)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:2718)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:2210)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope.toJson(RDDOperationScope.scala:51)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:144)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:714)
    org.apache.spark.SparkContext.textFile(SparkContext.scala:830)
    org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.textFile(JavaSparkContext.scala:181)
    com.nuevora.core.spark.commons.CommonFunctions.getJavaRDDFromFile(CommonFunctions.java:61)
    com.nuevora.core.spark.UpdateDataset.modifyInputDataset(UpdateDataset.java:103)
    com.nuevora.controllers.FormsValidatorServlet.service(FormsValidatorServlet.java:3070)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Executor logs are not helpful. But the final status of job is "succeeded "

Need help in solving this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding the paranamer jar which comes with the cloudera distribution